# Changing NSDate on custom object?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

My app has a custom object that contains an NSDate. 
I want to change this NSDate in my app, but this is not possible?

Code:

So this is a method from my object, that is supposed to alter the date, depending on another variable (sentcount):

```
(void)increaseSentAttempts
{
sentCount++;

NSDate *cal = [NSDate date];

if (sentCount < 3) {
    //add 1 minute
    cal = [cal dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
}
else if(sentCount < 10)
{
    //add 5 minutes
    cal = [cal dateByAddingTimeInterval:300];
}
else if(sentCount < 23)
{
    //add 1 hour
    cal = [cal dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
}
else {
    //add 15 hours
    cal = [cal dateByAddingTimeInterval:54000];
}


//sæt nextsent attribut
nextSendAttempt = cal;
```

}

nextSendAttempt is my NSDate in the custom object. But seeing as the app crashes, the nextsendattempt = cal; isnt possible.

Comment: This is totally possible. Post some code, or we won't be able to help you more without further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set a property on the NSDate-Member of your custom object?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSDate *myDate;
}
@property (retain) NSDate *myDate;
@end;
```

To change that value:

```
MyClass *obj = ...;
NSDate *newDate = ...;
NSLog(@"oldDate: %@",obj.myDate);
obj.myDate = newDate;
NSLog(@"newDate: %@",obj.myDate);
```

Comment: That wont work. As far as I understand, the NSDate object is immutable. So simply saying date = newdate, doesnt work as far as I can see in my debugging.

Comment: for me its working fine. `NSDate` is immutable but you are not modifying some values inside NSDate. What my code does is: create a new NSDate-instance and just modify the pointer to the NSDate-instance  of the MyClass-instance. So just the pointers to NSDate-instances are modified and not the NSDate-instance itself.

Comment: I found my error, and of course your response was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid stupid me. 
I needed to write:

```
self.nextSendAttempt = cal;
```

That'll work perfectly.

Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: `nextSendAttemp = cal` will also work in principle but the new cal-obj is newly created and autoreleased in `dateByAddingTimeInterval:`. Because you never retain the new NSDate-object the NSDate-object will be destroyed later and at accessing the NSDate you get an memory-error. So the retain was just missing which is done by the `nextSendAttemp`-property that is probarbly marked with `(retain)`